# php file returning error converting to JSON for android GET request

Tags: php, android, mysql, arrays, json

I've successfully setup retrofit 2 in android studio. The app displays the following error when doing a GET request to the mysql database via the php file.

expected begin_array but was string at line 1 column 1 path $

I've tried rewriting the php file several times but its not been successfull. Please see my current php file below.

```
 <?php
 header('Content-Type: application/json');
 include('conn.php');

$response = array();

//if(isset($_GET['1'])){
//$getid = $_GET['1'];

$read = "SELECT * FROM Cbt";


$result = $conn->query($read);

     while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

$cbtLog = [
$userId = $row['userId'];
$moodBefore = $row['moodBefore'];
$automaticThought = $row['automaticThought'];
$distortions = $row['distortions'];
$challengeThought = $row['challengeThought'];
$alternativeThought = $row['alternativeThought'];
$moodAfter = $row['moodAfter'];
 ];

 array_push($response, $cbtlog)
 }
 echo json_encode($response);
```

I would like the fix whatever the error is in the php file so that the results can be displayed on the android app. Please help me diagnose and fix the problem.

Comment: At the line `$cbtLog = [` what do you think is going on? Is it possible that `$userId = $row['userId'];` and the following lines should be in the form `'userId' => $row['userId'],`?

Answer (score 0):

Got it working

```
<?php
include('conn.php');

    enter code here

$query = "SELECT * FROM feelingFit_Cbt";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

$json_array = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

    $json_array[] =$row;
}

echo json_encode($json_array);
```